# Why catching a ball of high trajectory easier in Cricket match?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

my question is related with Projectile motion, it describes about the high velocity of ball on its trajectory. it asks about the conditions of height, time of flight, range as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two balls, which are both launched and caught at the same height (0) and the same distance ($d$) but flew to different heights ($h_1$ and $h_2$).

If we ignore air resistance, the vertical and horizontal motion can be considered separately. In other words, in just the vertical sense, the balls are thrown up to $h_1$ or $h_2$ and fall back down.

It takes longer to fall from a high height. So the ball that travels higher must take longer to reach the same destination.

Answer (score 0):

Because the farther it’s thrown usually the less speed it’ll have by the time it reaches the catcher due to air resistance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Long-winded version of the other answer:

Horizontal speed decreases over time due to air resistance. If you keep initial horizontal velocity, $v_{x0}$, constant and increase initial vertical velocity, $v_{y0}$, then the final horizontal velocity $v_{xf}\to 0$ as $v_{y0}\to \infty$. So a cricket player can just camp under a high-hit ball because it's essentially only moving in the vertical direction. Hitting a ball high eliminates a velocity vector, making the trajectory easier to track